# How to use Google Noto Color Emoji front from CDN via CSS

Tags: css, jsfiddle, google-font-api, google-fonts

I there any way to use [Google's color emoji font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/emoji/objects.html) from CDN? I was trying to use it in a jsfiddle but couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto Color Emoji';
  src: url(https://raw.githack.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/main/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf);
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can also give "Noto Colr Emoji Glyf" a try, which is COLRv1 font: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Colr+Emoji+Glyf

See [repo](https://github.com/googlefonts/color-fonts) and [demo](https://codepen.io/drott_chrome/pen/ExvaYxm).

But make sure to [check browser support](https://caniuse.com/colr-v1), as of writing it's only supported in Chrome 98+.

Comment: Hey wow I didn't really notice this when you wrote it. Works great thanks! Here's a little fiddle to play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/dbtazwhv/

Comment: It's important to note that you don't need to _replace_ your existing font in order to use the colored emojis from fonts like "Noto Color Emoji". Rather, you can add "Noto Color Emoji" at the end of your `font-family` style-value, such that it provides colored emojis (over the browser non-colored fallback), but lets your regular font (listed at start) do the lifting for regular characters.

Comment: Thank you, guys ❤ Indeed, @Venryx suggested a good approach for using emoji fonts.

Comment: Link no longer working, you can use this url instead : `https://raw.githack.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/main/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf`

Comment: thanks, @AryqsIpsum, I've update the answer

Comment: Found another one: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Color+Emoji`

Comment: Note that you can also use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Color+Emoji&display=swap">`. Even though it's not COLRv1, it can display more emojis such as  (identification card). It appears Noto Colr Emoji Glyf is still in active development and there are still missing emojis, so I wouldn't use it in production. As of today, Noto Colr Emoji Glyf fonts are almost the exact same size as Noto Color Emoji fonts, so maybe it's still mostly bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT google but you can try this alternative,

[EmojiOne](https://www.emojione.com/emoji/v2)

Here is the CDN

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/emojione

Comment: Yeah, thanks,  I went with them anyway, but I'm just interested if this can be done...